# JSF and Facebook

Tags: java, facebook, jsf

Is it possible to integrate facebook on a jsf page? Facebook only shows examples with php, but I already have an application written in jsf. I would like the single sign-on feature and be able to get my users pictures from facebook.

Maybe you have a little example on how you would do it :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It does not matter whether it's JSF or any other view technology. You can take a look at [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) - a Java API for using the Facebook Graph API. Or you can use the brand-new [Spring Social](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/11/03/socializing-spring-applications/), but it is not quite feature-rich yet.